# How to get position of added in adapter object

Tags: android, adapter

I'm making a bluetooth connection.

First I list the name and address of they in a `ListView`:

```
pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());


pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
```

I create aמ `onClick` event for each found device. Now I need get the `BluetoothDevice` in the `onClick` event, not only the address..

```
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener
                = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution:
Store all devices in array. When onItemClick is invoked the arg2 is actually the index in array which will be equal to index in your array.

Good solution:
Extend ArrayAdapter and implement your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Make a  arrayList  and store all the scanned devices in arrayList.

```
 ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceArrayList; //store all the scanned devices on it.
 BluetoothDevice bluetoothDeviceSelected = null;
 String name,address;

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  {

    bluetoothDeviceSelected = deviceArrayList.get(position);
    name=bluetoothDeviceSelected.getName();
    address=bluetoothDeviceSelected.getAddress();
}
```